# How can I hide posts that are over 2 years old

Tags: wp-query, date

I want to apply a rule to my site that filters out all blog posts that are over 2 years old.

I see some solutions that involve manually putting posts into a category and hiding the category but I want a solution that is fully automated.

Is there a way to tell WP that whenever you grab posts to apply this rule:

```
if( !is_admin() ) { 
    select posts where post date > two-years-ago-today
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi @rgalpin see in wp_query we can modify date range for posts https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters

Comment: Great! I have some grey areas in my knowledge of the scope of various WP objects and such. So, is there a place where I could apply this rule ONCE and have all wp_query instances enforce it?

Comment: hmm in that case you need to use filter called pre_get_posts https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `pre_get_posts` hook to modify the main query:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_old_posts' );
function filter_old_posts($query){
    if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()){
         add_filter('posts_where', $callback = function( $where = ''){
             $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 years')) . "'"; 
             return $where;
         });
         add_filter('getarchives_where', $callback );
    }
}
```

This will filter the main query posts to return posts newer than 2 years old.

There is also a second copy of the filter that uses `getarchives_where` to filter the archive widget results.

Comment: This looks like what I am trying to do. But I am getting an error: Fatal error: Call to a member function is_main_query() on array.

Comment: @rgalpin Oops my bad. There was a typo in the answer. I typed `$query->query->is_main_query()` by mistake.

Comment: Thanks! That works great on the list of posts returned on my blog main page. My list of archived posts is not seeing the filter. Is there a way to catch that WP Archived list that runs down the right panel?

Comment: @rgalpin You are welcome.Do you mean the archive widget or the archive.php page?

Comment: The archive widget.

Comment: @rgalpin The archive widget uses `wp_get_archives()` to get a list of the archives. You have 2 ways to alter it, either remove the `$query->is_main_query()` to affect every query on the website ( not recommended) or make another copy of `posts_where` filter and change it's name to `getarchives_where`. This is the filter that `wp_get_archive` uses to filter posts. You might also want to change `$where=' '` to `$where` in your new copied filter too.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i meant. This is an standard hook to use when you want to modify the query results.

Comment: J Thanks! Would like to post the final code block for anyone who it may help. I would like to post it so that it is more readable but I don't see how to do that in this comment block. Is it ok to Answer my own question in order to post it?

Comment: @rgalpin You are welcome. I updated my answer and included your second filter.